# How to delete Realm if I instantiate realm as a class property?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Based on the examples provided by the Realm team, I have instantiated the realm and bind it to a class variable called 'realm' like this:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let realm = try! Realm()
```

I think it makes sense and makes the code more readable. However, my project is in it's early stage, the objects are changing quite a lot and I am trying to avoid performing migrations with this:

```
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded = true
```

Naturally this leads to trouble since I am trying to delete a Realm file after opening the Realm which is excplicitly forbidden in the [docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#deleting-realm-files). I have followed similar design pattern in my UIViewController classes as well, which makes refactoring a bit cumbersome.

**The question is:** 
Is it bad practice to bind Realm instance to a class property as I have done? Should I always reference to Realm with let realm = try! Realm() block when I need to read my objects? Or is there some way to delete the Realm without deleting all the class wide realm instances?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this pattern:

Singleton `DataManager` which is used to manage `Realm` access.  It can wrap all the `try`s, for example:

```
class DataManager {
    static let shared = DataManager()

    func add(_ object: Object, update: Bool = true) {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(object, update: update)
            }
        } catch {
            print (error)
        }
    }

    ...Other shared Realm methods...
}
```

I also have a `MigrationManager` singleton, which as the name suggests, handles Realm migrations.  It's method get called very early - well before `DataManager` methods are called

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    ...
    MigrationManager.shared.migrate()
    ...
}
```

some `MigrationManager` code

```
class MigrationManager {
    static let shared = MigrationManager()

    let schemaVersion: UInt64 = 3

    private var migrationBlock: MigrationBlock? {
        return { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        ...
        }
    }

    func migrate() {
        let config = Realm.Configuration(
            schemaVersion: schemaVersion,
            migrationBlock: migrationBlock)

        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dmorrow for quick reply. This seems ingenious, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

When you call `try! Realm()`, Realm will internally store a cached reference to the instantiated `Realm` object. That way, calling `try! Realm()` on subsequent times will recycle that instance.

As such, it's generally considered best practice to *not* store `Realm` instances as properties of long-lived objects, like the app delegate, and to only call `try! Realm()` at the times when you actually need it.

You should configure your `defaultConfiguration` as early as you can in your app delegate's execution.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    // Configure the default Realm
    let configuration = Realm.Configuration()
    configuration.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded = true
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = configuration

    return true
}
```

This way, any calls to `Realm()` after the fact will incorporate the delete upon migration logic. There's no reason to save a copy of `Realm` before then.

If you're using storyboards, sometimes `let realm = try! Realm()` as a property in a `UIViewController` subclass may end up getting called before the app delegate has had a chance to fire. In which case, you can manually set up the storyboard logic in the app delegate too, after Realm has been configured.

Comment: Thank you @TiM, this clarified things a lot 